# WP get posts with 2 condition

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post type with 2 conditions :

First : ACF field with start date

Secondly : ACF field is empty

I would like to have first, a list ordered by "start date" (ACF field) and secondly a list ordered by publication date.

When I using get_posts, only first condition works :

```
            $args_infos = array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'infos',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'emetteur',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => 132,
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN', //to hide expired posts
                    )
                ),
                'meta_key' => 'start_date', //the reason why, only posts with start date are showing
                'meta_type' => 'date',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Looks like your meta args should be wrapped in a meta_query array, check here for examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I tried with an array but my orderby didnt works ... I think i forgot something

Comment: @rich
 'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'OR',array('key'     => 'debut_IP'),
            array('key'     => '',) ) what's the second key ? Because the field is 'empty' -> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246355/order-by-multiple-meta-key-and-meta-value/246358#246358

Comment: To be honest im not sure, that example does not seem to be in the link you posted and does not look right

Comment: So i dont understand your first comment :/ can you give me an example ?

Comment: Actually see here, this might be a better solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890475/1793797